# where is incrontab -e configuration files

Tags: server, 20.04

a colleague define incrontab, so I didn't find anything in /etc/incron.d/
I would like to find where is file he defined but I don't know where `incrontab -e` save it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer for cron and have a look in */var/spool* and saw a ***/var/spool/incron/***_ folder which contain $USER file, one with my colleague username… and it contains attended incron tasks